# looking for transparent DNS proxy

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy

ISP are said to use transparent DNS proxy, to hijack DNS to serve data faster.
Does anyone know ip and port of one of those reliable proxies?

EDIT:
As most of you didn't understand what this mean, here is the link: https://www.dnsleaktest.com/what-is-transparent-dns-proxy.php

Hope It helps.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding how DNS works, and conflating two very different things ISPs do to it (one good and one bad).  Read up on DNS some more and you will have your answer.

Comment: @FalconMomot: It is not a misunderstanding. Please look at this website: https://www.dnsleaktest.com/what-is-transparent-dns-proxy.php. I want to do exactly that.

Comment: I think actually it is the people who made that page who don't understand what they are doing.  The correct terminology for that device is a recursive nameserver (or, alternatively, you could use a forwarder to a recursive nameserver), and it is a basic part of how DNS works.  They are also mention some people are blocking outbound DNS traffic to other resolvers, which you can do (it's a separate function).  This is not in any way uncommon (or malicious).  The IPs you are asking for are merely public resolvers; 8.8.8.8 is one.

Comment: 8.8.8.8 is a DNS, not a proxy. Proxy could fake my phone DNS (which is unchangeable in settings), so that it uses ISP DNS and not phone DNS. Most free transparent proxies intercept 53 port, however they are slow and unreliable. 8.8.8.8 as a DNS can't do it.

Comment: @ripazha What is described in your link is "breaking the internet" (intercepting traffic destined for e.g. `8.8.8.8`, handing it to a local server, and having that server respond back to you can be accomplished through all sorts of nasty hackery, but it's a terrible idea!) - In any case this question as written is off-topic for Server Fault: We are not your research assistants, and we do not generally assemble "lists of things" as answers. If you can rework your question in the form of an actual, practical system administration problem ("I need to do X because Y. How can I do it?") re-ask it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a core part of most DNS servers. You can set up Bind or Windows DNS and they will cache DNS requests by default. Your ISP's DNS servers are doing the same thing, every time someone requests a lookup they cache the result. If you're using a Linksys etc it's doing it too. Don't configure your clients to use Google's DNS servers directly unless you have a specific reason to do so.

Comment: There is a reason: Windows Phone 8. Any wifi without DHCP won't work. You cannot set DNS, static IP, etc. You can use only proxy, only ip and port based. Faking DNS is needed, if you don't want to use DHCP.

Comment: DHCP sets your DNS server. The proxy option is for a web (HTTP) proxy, not DNS.

Comment: Please look at my edit.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins Actually this is something nasty that some ISPs actually do: They intercept all traffic on port 53, shunt it to a local server, and return replies masquerading as the DNS server you *thought* you were talking to. This theoretically saves them some bandwidth (they can cache more traffic), but it's a pretty underhanded and internet-breaking thing to do. AOL used to be infamous for this, among their many other DNS-related sins.

Comment: I understand how ISPs can act as man in the middle, originally the post was asking how to improve query performance. A local, cached DNS server would be the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to toss another option in the ring here, dnsmasq is a great no-frills DNS forwarder that does exactly what you're looking to do.  It has options for some basic static DNS entry capability if that's your bag.  This is usually the daemon that is running, in one form or another, on SOHO routers, Linux router/firewalls like pfSense and Mikrotik Routerboard devices, and on custom home router firmwares like DD-WRT.  It's lightweight and effective, and if you have *nix hardware in place, it's a heck of a lot easier to set up than a BIND install.

Comment: Yeah, it's easier, but it requires pretty good router. My solution doesn't need it :)